# Plug identification, used on 70 ampere relay

Tags: relay, identification, wire-terminals

I have a terminal off of a Deere 6170M tractor for a 70 ampere relay. The terminal appears to be either 0.374" (9.5mm) wide, or then 0.375" (9.53mm) wide. Deere tells me their part number is 57M5792, but that part doesn't fit. I am missing a few connectors, since I am not the first person to tackle this job.

[image]

[image]

I've searched Digikey using the listed widths, but all the terminals are a more basic style. I would like to have a terminal with the extra tabs for high current.

[Here's the search.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392?s=N4IgjCBcoEwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzACwBsVcA7CALqEAOALlCAMocBOASwB2AcxABfQmAAMVAByIQKSBhwFiZEDBkMYMEIR10KLdl0i8BI8RKnatHXPwC2IrCwlA)

Comment: This category of connector are generically called "faston" or "spade" connectors, of which searches will probably show only the basic kind.  The contact area looks fairly clean and it isn't broken though; if they end up being unique, I'd open up the wire clamps with a dental explorer, insert new wire, close with plyers, solder (electronics solder, not pipe solder), and cover the shank liberally with heat-shrink tubing.  If the exposed copper is from acid damage, cover with dielectric grease after installing.  Must make strong physical connection or the grease will interfere and cause failure.

Comment: @rdtsc  Edit: The problem is I'm missing a few connectors, as I'm not the first one to try to fix this socket.

Comment: 9.5mm / 9.53mm spades are used for car radiator fan relays and H4 headlamps. This is where one could canibalize them if high quality ones are not immediately available.

Comment: What's the wire gauge/size?  What's the stranding?  Insulation OD?

Comment: IEC calls these quick-disconnect.  interesting, this looks like a copper contact part attached to a stainless steel spring part, rather than the usual one-piece  bronze connector

Comment: this looks like this fits inside some sort of housing  what are the markings on the housing?

Comment: what is written on the crimp tube?  (looks like "MIA" or "VIW" in the photo)

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні There are no markings on the plastic terminal holder. The marking on the crimp is "MIA", which comes up on Google searches as an electrical connector, but not a lot of info.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen The wire is 12 AWG 37/28 with an average insulation thickness, I didn't measure it.

Comment: The only place that I've seen terminals of similar construction was on APC (https://www.apc.com/us/en/) UPS batteries.  Though those were fully insulated.

Comment: Probably not quite right... but the closest my searching has come (no affiliation, no prior experience, no opinions): https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/terminals-mta-modular-system.html

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen If you could turn that last comment link into a proper answer I would accept it for other people finding this, as the terminal is exactly what we needed. Thanks so much. It took over a week to get to the US, but that was OK, we have what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest my searching has come (no affiliation, no prior experience, no opinions):

https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/terminals-mta-modular-system.html

[image]

From the site:

Home  >  Fusing & Circuit Protection  >  MTA Modular Fuse & Relay Holding System  >  Terminals

"**Terminals**

Non-insulated crimp terminals for use in the MTA modular fuse and relay holding system. For connection to mini and maxi blade fuses, micro, mini and high power (maxi) relays. Available to suit a range of cable sizes.
"